# Hosting a NodeJs React app with Lightsail

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, api, host, amazon-lightsail

I am very new with hosting.

I built an app with React, NodeJs, Express. Classic MERN project.

I wonder how to host it ? I read about Amazon Lightsail, but I have to choose OS.

If I pick Ubuntu, will I be able to install Nodejs, npm, host my API with https, etc ?

Thank you for infos guys.

Comment: Instead of thinking of hosting in a traditional sense, think about how you can use cloud services natively which can be much more effective in terms of being able to scale and from a cost perspective (pay for what you use). e.g. you can serve your React app from CloudFront, and your NodeJS apis can be Lambdas with API Gateway (then you don't even need Express).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be asking a few things here.

In terms of *how* you should be hosting: depending on your goals, Amazon Web Services may be a little more than you're looking for at the moment. If you're just getting started with web hosting and deployment I would highly recommend taking a look at something more straightforward(and free!) such as [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/). This might help you get a grasp on the process of deployment, and they have a decent [getting started guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs) specifically for node.

That said, if you are certain you'd like to dive in with Amazon Web Services there are [several different services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54981074/aws-what-are-the-exact-differences-between-ec2-beanstalk-and-lightsail) available to choose from (including lightsail) that you also may want to consider before continuing.

And finally to answer your main question: ***Yes***, if you choose an Ubuntu distro for an OS you will indeed be able to install npm, node, and all the packages you'll require for your app (likely via a command line interface). I am not personally familiar with the specifics of Lightsail, but they have their own [getting started guide](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/search?s=Get%20started%20Linux&c=getting-started) you might want to read through for linux setups.

---

Comment: Thank you very much ! I'm gonna go with Heroku :) Thanks a lot